# Comparing two df's of different lengths, receiving "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to compare two df's. If the same ID appears in df2 I want to add it to df1 to a "count" column.

After this, I want to then add all rows from df2 with unique ID's to df1.

The first time I run the code it works (df1 count is increased and the new ID's are added as new rows), the second time however the "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" error is raised.
I assume this is due to the number of rows of df1 differing to df2.
Is there a way to resolve this or another approach I should take?

```
import pandas as pd

boxes1 = {'ID': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'],
         'Shape': ['Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Square','Square','Square','Rectangle']
        }

boxes2 = {'ID': ['9','10','1','4','5','14','7','8'],
         'Shape': ['Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Square','Square','Square','Rectangle']
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(boxes1, columns= ['ID','Shape'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(boxes2, columns= ['ID','Shape'])


df1['count'] = 0
df2['count'] = 0

#Compares dfs and adds 1 to df1 if same ID appears
df1.loc[(df3["ID"] == df1["ID"]), 'count'] += 1

#Compares dfs and adds any unique IDs to df1
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df3]).drop_duplicates('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Where `df3` is set?

Comment: *"#Compares dfs and adds 1 to df1 if same ID appears"*. Appear at the same location in the 2 dataframes? (ID: 4, 5, 7, 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby_agg`:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2]) \
        .groupby('ID', sort=False) \
        .agg({'ID': 'first', 'Shape': 'first', 'count': lambda x: len(x)-1}) \
        .reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
>>> out
    ID      Shape  count
0    1  Rectangle      1
1    2  Rectangle      0
2    3     Square      0
3    4  Rectangle      1
4    5     Square      1
5    6     Square      0
6    7     Square      1
7    8  Rectangle      1
8    9  Rectangle      0
9   10  Rectangle      0
10  14     Square      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) which does not require same number of rows and index for `df1` and `df2`, as follows:

replace your code `df1.loc[(df3["ID"] == df1["ID"]), 'count'] += 1` to the following code:

```
df1.loc[df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID']), 'count'] += 1
```

**Result:**

```
print(df1)

  ID      Shape  count
0  1  Rectangle      1
1  2  Rectangle      0
2  3     Square      0
3  4  Rectangle      1
4  5     Square      1
5  6     Square      0
6  7     Square      1
7  8  Rectangle      1
```

Then, after your last line of code:

(modified `df3` to `df2`):

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df1)

    ID      Shape  count
0    1  Rectangle      1
1    2  Rectangle      0
2    3     Square      0
3    4  Rectangle      1
4    5     Square      1
5    6     Square      0
6    7     Square      1
7    8  Rectangle      1
8    9  Rectangle      0
9   10  Rectangle      0
10  14     Square      0
```